# Get the lowest Score of each distinct Name and distinct Group

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Need to get the lowest Score of each distinct Name and distinct Group.  Thank you.

```
Data:
Group   Name    Score
A   N1  1
B   N1  5
C   N1  3
A   N1  4
A   N2  2
A   N3  6
A   N1  8
B   N1  7
B   N2  9
```

Result:

```
A   N1  1
B   N1  5
C   N1  3
A   N2  2
A   N3  6
B   N2  9
```

Comment: And you tried, what?  This is a very simple `MIN()` with `GROUP BY`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select [Group],   Name ,  min( Score)
 from my_table
 group by [Group], Name
```

Comment: Why answer this? Doesn't that just promote more low-quality questions like this??

Comment: @sgeddes  backtics removed

Comment: Probably still should escape `group` though, it's a reserved word.   Brackets I believe for access...

Comment: @sgeddes    square brackets.. thanks  ..for the suggestions